# jQuery UI autocomplete with list of javascript objects

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Right now I'm trying to do some autocomplete with a list of facebook friends, and the way I'd like it to work is I'd like the autocomplete display one field (name), but when the form is submitted, for it to post instead the other field, the ID

What would be a good way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Going to need some code/What have you tried?

Comment: That's the thing.
I looked around for some examples, but couldn't get much going (I could automplete an array of strings and do the basic things mentioned on the websites, but nothing more. Documentation seems kind of... incomplete), and most stuff online seems outdated since apparently autocomplete was recently revamped.

Sorry if I should have put some code here

Comment: I think at minimum to get it working you'll want to look at jQuery UI's autocomplete and attempt to populate it with a list of Facebook friends.